# Why this cell do not autoresize in IE but works well in Firefox?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

http://isikota.com/mail/ios/home.html

In firefox it works fine
In ie it looks horrible.

If I send the html via email it also looks horrible.

The key here is this edge:

```
                <td style="width: 341px; height: 100%">
<img alt="" height="100%" width="341" src="http://example.com/mail/Ios/image/iphone/2.png" class="style3">
</td>
```

Basically that cell should "expand" given that the height is 100%. In firefox it expands properly. In ie it doesn't. In email it also doesn't expand.

Comment: In my experience you cannot rely on the height attribute to work with percentages, at least not in any reliable fashion.

Comment: When asking questions about IE, please also always specify the IE version(s) that you're testing with.

Comment: 100% of what? Remove the height from both the `td` and `img` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fixed height in your `<td>` and after that you image should expand 100% on IE.

Comment: I think the whole point of not setting fixed height in the TD is because the height should be flexible.